# Laravel multiple select filter for categories, only get one select as output

Tags: php, laravel, filter, eloquent

In laravel 8, I am filtering blog articles by category. However when I select multiple categories in my select menu. I do get the proper request . for example: articles/category/?category_ids=3,4

But it will only output one selected filter. If I select 2 filters it just selects that next filter as if I only selected that one. (I also use Axios but the request is done proper, so its in my Controller)

Here is my code I tried:

```
   $data['articles'] = Article::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($category_ids){
            $query->whereHas('category_id', '=', $category_ids)->where('premium',0);
        ;})->get();
```

I also tried:

```
 $data['articles'] = Article::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($category_ids){
            $query->whereIn('category_id', [$category_ids])->where('premium',0);
        ;})->get();
```

So how do I get to query both or more category id's ?

I am using a pivot table:

Articles can have many Categories

Categories can have many Articles

I use article_category as a pivot table

Comment: how do you get `$category_ids` ? show the code

Comment: how you save category_id for articles? if you have one category for each article you should use `where in (3,4)` for query

Comment: It is a many to many relationship, one category can have more articles and other way around.  I save the code:   $category_ids = $request->get('category_ids'); 

It is a select element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking for relationship existence in many-to-many relations, the check is still to be done against the id in the categories table.

Try this

```php
$category_ids = collect(explode(',', $request->category_ids))
    ->map(fn($i) => trim($i))
    ->all();

$data['articles'] => Article::whereHas('category', fn($query) => 
    $query->whereIn('categories.id', $category_ids)
        ->where('categories.premium', 0)
)->get();
```

Comment: Hi! I get the same as with some other code: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\3lly\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 962

Comment: So I read it needs to be an array for this function to work so I put [$category_ids] brackets around it, but then I get: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `articles` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join `article_category` on `categories`.`id` = `article_category`.`category_id` where `articles`.`id` = `article_category`.`article_id` and `id` in (2,3))) 

I try to understandwhat it means. Just wanted to share it.

Comment: @Codelly Have updated the answer to get the category_ids from request and prepare an array before passing in the whereIn and qualified the columns with table names to remove ambiguity

Comment: @Codelly Have removed the typo from the answer now it has `$category_ids` as array, column names in **whereIn** and **where** clauses qualified with table name to remove any ambiguity - so should work - check and pls let me know if otherwise

Comment: It works ! But why ? I dont understand ? Do you have a moment to explain? I already gave the comma and all ? What is happening haha ? Thank you so much !

Comment: @Codelly Okay first we exploded the category_ids from request into an array then we mapped over the array elements and trimmed any extra white spaces using collection **map()** function and reconverted the collection to array with **all()**. Then we check existence of Category (related model record) with constraints where the **id** of the records must be in the array of **category_ids** and **premium** column should have value 0

Comment: Thanks so much  for the answer and the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the categories and then make the query like this.

```
$categories = explode(',',$request->categories);

$data['articles'] = Article::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($categories){
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $categories)->where('premium',0);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articles` where `category_id` in (2, 3) and `premium` = 0)

 I get this suddenly!!

 if I just do toArray() on my own code it says in my blade : Trying to get property 'image' of non-object  . I already do a , with a join statement in Axios (javascript) So the request seems to be okay. But somehow it does not read multiple id's

Comment: Hi @Codelly replace the category_id with the column which exists in  your article table

Comment: Okay will try (Its a pivot table by the way)

Comment: @Codelly can you add the schema in your original answer for the table

Comment: I updated my answer, is that enough info ? A Category just has a name and an id thats it.

Comment: @Codelly I have updated my answer, can you please try it once

Comment: Thanks for the help :D got it with the answer above !

Comment: @Codelly It's my pleasure and I'm glad that your problem got resolved :)